# Adding workflow into "Services" menu, automate it (OmniGraffle)

Tags: macos, automator

I have a file in OmniGraffle that has a lot of text items. I need to render all the text items as images and use LaTeX as my renderer. Assuming that MacTex is installed, I can easily do this task, one text item at a time, in the following way ([Source](http://fmilo.blogspot.com/2011/04/omnigraffle-and-latex.html)):

1. double click the item and make sure all the text is selected (Command+A)
2. from the "Services" menu, click on: "Text" Latexisation (LaTeXiT)

This is easy but can be painful when having a lot of text, as in my case. I tried to assign a keyboard shortcut to this menu item, but still painful.

**Question:** Is it possible to to create a workflow in automator to help me batch convert all selected items into latex text, and maybe add this workflow as a service in the "Services" menu? Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you.